# Run spicy.stats ANOVA test for all unique values in a data frames column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, anova, scipy.stats

I have a data frame which consist of many cities and their corresponding temperature:

```py
               CurrentThermostatTemp
City                                
Cradley Heath                   20.0
Cradley Heath                   20.0
Cradley Heath                   18.0
Cradley Heath                   15.0
Cradley Heath                   19.0
...                              ...
Walsall                         16.0
Walsall                         22.0
Walsall                         20.0
Walsall                         20.0
Walsall                         20.0

[6249 rows x 1 columns]
```

The unique values are:

```py
Index(['Cradley Heath', 'ROWLEY REGIS', 'Smethwick', 'Oldbury',
       'West Bromwich', 'Bradford', 'Bournemouth', 'Poole', 'Wareham',
       'Wimborne',
       ...
       'St. Helens', 'Altrincham', 'Runcorn', 'Widnes', 'St Helens',
       'Wakefield', 'Castleford', 'Pontefract', 'Walsall', 'Wednesbury'],
      dtype='object', name='City', length=137)
```

My aim is to do the one-way ANOVA test i.e.

```py
from scipy.stats import f_oneway
```

for all unique values in the data frame. So do

```py
SciPy.stats.f_oneway("all unique values")
```

And receive the output: One-way ANOVA test for all variables gives {} with p-value {}
This is what I have tried many times but does not work:

```py
all = Tempvs.index.unique()
Tempvs.sort_index(inplace=True)
for n in range(len(all)):
    truncated = Tempvs.truncate(all[n], all[n])
    print(f_oneway(truncated))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC you want an ANOVA test where each sample contains the values `Temp` of unique elements `City`. If this is the case, you can do

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import scipy.stats as sps

# I create a sample dataset
index = ['Cradley Heath', 'ROWLEY REGIS',
         'Smethwick', 'Oldbury',
         'West Bromwich', 'Bradford', 
         'Bournemouth', 'Poole', 'Wareham',
         'Wimborne','St. Helens', 'Altrincham', 
         'Runcorn', 'Widnes', 'St Helens',
         'Wakefield', 'Castleford', 'Pontefract', 
         'Walsall', 'Wednesbury']
np.random.seed(1)
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'City': np.random.choice(index, 500),
    'Temp': np.random.uniform(15, 25, 500)
})

# populate a list with all
# values of unique Cities
values = []
for city in df.City.unique():
    _df = df[df.City==city]
    values.append(_df.Temp.values)

# compute the ANOVA
# with starred *list
# as arguments
sps.f_oneway(*values)
```

that, in this case, will give

```
F_onewayResult(statistic=0.4513685152123563, pvalue=0.9788508507035195)
```

> PS: do not use `all` as a variable, because it is a builtin python function, see https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all

Comment: Thank you very much sir. Appreciate the help

Comment: YVW. If you think that this solves your issue, please accept the answer. Thanks.